# How do I make sure my notification sounds play reliably on all devices?

Tags: android, audio, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app sets up two notification channels, each with its own sound effect. But users are saying the sounds aren't working right on some devices, like the Pixel. Here's my setup. Is there anything I could do to improve the channel settings to ensure that the sounds (two .mp3 files kept in res/raw/) play as reliably as possible (as background notifications, not foreground)? Are there better audio settings or formats or configuration that I am missing?

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Here's the code creating the channels:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH

            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setFlags(FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                .build()

            val newChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance)
            newChannel.description = description
            newChannel.importance = IMPORTANCE_HIGH

            newChannel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes)
            return newChannel
}
```

And here's code for obtaining the sound URI:

```
private fun createSoundUri(soundNum: Int, context: Context):Uri? {
val scheme = ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
val packageName = context.packageName
val root = "$scheme://$packageName/"

return when(soundNum) {
    0 -> Uri.parse(root + R.raw.sound1)
    1 -> Uri.parse(root + R.raw.sound2)
    2 -> Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI
    else -> null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I received data using FCM then started an activity initiating the media player in my app.

`MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ringtone);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();`

Maybe you could use this idea

Comment: Thanks. I think, though, that this only works for foreground notifications and not background, where you have to depend on the channel settings.